# Extending AbstractUser in django

Tags: python, django

I was trying to subclass AbstractUser and stuck in an error on running migrate, and makemigrations says `No changes detected`

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "auth_group" does not exist
```

model:

```
class SubClient(AbstractUser):
    client_id = models.ForeignKey(Client)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=15)
```

added in settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myadmin.SubClient'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error means the `auth_group` table does not exist in your database. Which means you did not run Django's migration files (python files describing database structure and its changes over time).

As you have your own models, you first need to create migration files for them by running `python manage.py makemigrations`.

Then run `python manage.py migrate` to run all migrations (Django's + yours), this will create all database tables (including `auth_croup`).

Read the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/) to lean more about migrations.

Comment: ERRORS:
myadmin.SubClient.groups: (fields.E304) Reverse accessor for 'SubClient.groups' clashes with reverse accessor for 'SubClient.groups'.
        HINT: Add or change a related_name argument to the definition for 'SubClient.groups' or 'SubClient.groups'.  This kind of errors for almost all columns. How to clear this?

Comment: @rahul I'm sorry, my first answer was mistaken, I updated it, this should be better.

Comment: sorry, i have already done those steps, but forgot to mention it in question. makemigrations says no changes detected, and migrate gives above mentioned error

Comment: @rahul Do you have `'django.contrib.auth'` in your [INSTALLED_APPS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/fr/1.8/ref/settings/#installed-apps)?

Comment: Yes, INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'myadmin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
)

Answer (score 0):

when using AbstractUser could i use django's user's builtin password-reset workflow such as password-reset, password-reset-done etc.
the reason i am asking is that i extended user model using AbstractUser but these built-in function not working and i do not get any error but it redirects me to search page and there is no documentation on the internet regarding this issue:

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

path('password-reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset.html'),
         name='password-reset'),
    path('password-reset/done/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_done.html'),
         name='password-reset-done'),
    path('password-reset-confirm/<uidb65>/<token>/',
         auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_confirm.html'),
         name='password-reset-confirm'),
    path('password-reset-complete/s',
         auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(template_name='accounts/password_reset_complete.html'),
         name='password-reset-complete')
```